# Change height of panel box for xyplot

Tags: r, plot, panel, box

My plot (with `xyplot`, `lattice`) looks like:

[image]

It looks pretty good, but how can I control the height of the grey panel-boxes?

I tried:

```
strip=strip.custom( par.strip.text=list(cex=2,lines=5,lineheight=2))
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try with `xyplot(..., par.strip = list(lines = 2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the strip height:

```
library(lattice)
Depth <- equal.count(quakes$depth, number=8, overlap=.1)
xyplot(lat ~ long | Depth, data = quakes, par.strip = list(lines = 5, cex = 0.5))
```

[image]